# When two planes intersect, can there be 3 vectors that are pairwise orthogonal and 1 one of the vector lies on both planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My answer to the last paragraph is:

The set of vectors does not form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ because **x** and **y** are not orthogonal.

I am not sure if my answer is correct as I do not have the solution manual. However, assuming it is correct, I am surprised that is true as I had expected the vectors to be orthogonal to each other because I cross product the normal of the plane $U$ with **x** and cross product the normal of the plane $V$ with **x**.

Given any two planes that intersect, will the vectors **x,y,z** constructed as above never be
pairwise orthogonal?

Furthermore, given the information in the question, would it be possible to immediately/quickly conclude that the vectors **x,y,z** will not be pairwise orthogonal but does span $\mathbb{R^3}$? In other words, are there some properties of planes, orthogonal vectos, etc that if I had known about them, would allow me to expect the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

The basis can be orthonormal if and only if the normal vectors of the two planes are perpendicular. Notice that y and z are the normal vectors and perpendicularity is a pairwise property.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** For the answer to be technically correct, you should normalise x, y and z. This is omitted for clarity and ease of expression.

This can be done without too much work:

(1) $(1,-1,2)\times(3,2,1)=(-5,5,5)$ and we can scale to $x = (-1,1,1)$.

(2) $(1,-1,2)\times(-1,1,1) = (-3,-3,0)$ and we can scale to $y = (1,1,0)$.

(3) $(3,2,1)\times(-1,1,1) = (1,-4,5) = z$.

Now $span(x,y)$ is a plane and we can check that $z$ is not in this plane. So $\left \{x,y,z\right \}$ generate the entire space; that is they are a basis.

However, $y \cdot z = -3 \neq 0$ and so this basis is **not** orthogonal. In fact, the basis would only be orthogonal if the normal vectors of the two planes are orthogonal - they are not.